# Query multiple values in a single ASP field

Tags: asp-classic

Is there a way to request from a server, which uses ASP, multiple records and have them all displayed on a page using a single URL? Say something like `http://foo.com/bar.asp?nums=1:2`? such that one page loads with two pages worth of information?

Comment: Not with the database I'm trying to pull data from. The current database I'm looking at isn't setup to query multiple instances of the same variable as you suggested (i.e., nums=1&nums=2) though I wish it were. I appreciate the asp code, but the database isn't mine, so I'm not able to do much with it.

Comment: Erm.... What database is it? This is a simple 'or', query. SELECT * FROM tbl where nums=1 or num=2
Your question also makes no mention of a database whatsoever. The answer given is how to get the values from the querystring. How you query your database is a separate question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using multiple querystring variables with the same name like:

> http://foo.com/bar.asp?nums=1&nums=2

Then, in your asp page:

```
<%
for i=1 to Request.QueryString("nums").Count
  Response.Write(Request.QueryString("n")(i) & "<br>")
  'obviously here, you would be querying your database
next
%>
```